# Solidify conundrum?

Tags: modifiers

I stumbled across a solidify issue, I cannot wrap my head around.
I have a simple mesh, consisting of three faces.

[image]

When adding a solidify modifier, I expect to get an object with three walls, where every angle is square. However, whatever I try, tweaking the various solidify parameters, what I get is something like the following, with a skewed rim.

[image]

Did I hit a bug, or is it a limitation of the solidify modifier?
Is there a workaround?

[blend file](https://eezacque.home.xs4all.nl/solidify.blend)

Answer (score 1):

To my eyes this is how solidify will behave on these faces.  It's connecting that front edge to the new vertex created on the inner corner on the backside.

You can try Extrude Manifold with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> which should be able to create the shape you want, and will automatically remove inside faces.

Comment: A manual extrude is too much work for the actual design, which is a lot more complicated. I prefer a non-destructive solution. Looks like blender is too limited here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ... one face is flipped - it creates a twist of newly generated faces. Check your **Face Orientation**

[image]

But ... corrected orientation doesn't solve your issue since blender doesn't knowhow to interpret corner. There is a several ways ...

[image]

You can select edge and use **Edge Split** operator, but this what you would expect as result.

[image]

---

You can fake it ... use your mesh with flipped face and Edge Split (as previously). Visually you get what you want, but geometry is overlapping now and will cause issues with other modifiers.

[image]

[image]

So ... there isn't a proper solution for you. I don't know if other apps can solve it better.

Comment: Face orientation is not the problem here, what I'm looking for is an object which sits flats on a surface...

Comment: I know, that's what I tried to write. Edit: You can fake it - to let sit on a surface, but it will cause other issues. There is not a solution for you from what I know. Sorry